# How to generate list of groups that own files in /tmp or other file system folders?

Tags: files, linux-mint, ls, cut

I'm using `ls -l /tmp` to list the files and their permissions in tmp folder. However, how do I list of groups that own files in the in /tmp folder or perhaps in other folder in file system? I'm hoping to sticking to `ls` and `cut` commands for now if possible.

Comment: Welcome, did you try something so far?

Comment: `ls -la /tmp | sort -uk3,4` will show you exactly one line for each user-group combo; `-uk4,4`  one line for each group. Assuming that the filenames don't contain newlines (and many other gotchas).

Comment: @user414777 This gave me an idea on how to approach this. I appreciate for answering the question.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Yeah, finally got it and thanks!

Comment: With GNU find you can probably use `find .. -printf '<gid_format>\n' | sort | uniq -c` but I'm on a phone and don't remember WTF the `<gid_format>` is ;-)